# Can not import module into file, within virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cretaed virtualenv like: `python3 -m venv venv_name`

Then activated virtualenv: `source full/path/to/venv_name/bin/activate`

Within this (activated) environment installed psycopg2 like:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-psycopg2
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Then if I open this folder in terminal, switch to `python` and try: `import psycopg2`, it works.

Then I created   file `test.py` into `venv_name` folder and added to this file: `import psycopg2`.

Tried execute this file using pycharm and getting error: `No module named 'psycopg2'`

So virtualenv is activated and module `psycopg2` installed, but why I can't import module into file, within this virtualenv?

Comment: See also Yevhen's reply but things to point out: pip  and pip3 are not using the same python, specifically so if the import works on "python" but not on "python3"..

Comment: @rasjani That's not necessarily true. `pip` **could** be an alias to `pip3`, though doesn't have to be. Same as `python` **could** be an alias to `python3`. And to be precise, those aliases also could be independent, i.e. `pip` could be an alias to `pip3` alongside with `python` not being an alias to `python3` and vice versa.

Comment: True - specifically when working with virtualenv'.  But considering that if venv was activated when doing pip install, it could hint that package went to global location, not into venv .. So, there is a chance that it was different interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means PyCharm uses a different interpreter, i.e. not from your `venv_name`. You can set it up to use the python from `venv_name` with

`PyCharm` -> `Preferences` -> `Project: <your project>` -> `Python Interpreter` -> in "Python Interpreter" field choose "Show all" -> `+` to add new -> `Virtual Environment` -> `Existing environment` -> Select path to `full/path/to/venv_name/bin/python`.

***Another thing***: Your python scripts are not meant to be in the `venv_name` directory. They should be alongside it.

Comment: In my case instead of `PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project: <your project> .. ` it is: `PyCharm -> File -> Settings -> Project: <your project> .. `